# $l$-adic expansion of 1/2

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I try to understand how to find a $l$-adic expansion of rational numbers. So I tried with $\frac{1}{2}$. Unfortunately I failed.

What I know\think:

We have two cases.
What if $l$ is odd? What if $l$ is even?

I have to find:$$\frac{1}{2} = \sum_{i=\infty}^{\infty} z_i\cdot l^{-i},$$ $z_i\in\{ 1,...,l-1\}$ and $l \ge 2$.

Comment: If $p$ is even, then $p=2$, and so $\frac{1}{2} = 2^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} z_i p^{-i}$, where $z_i = 1$ when $i=1$, and 0 otherwise.  For other primes, the expansion will vary.  Can you work it out for $p=3$?

Comment: I've done a mistake. I want to say that p is not prime. So I replaced p with l now.

Comment: Another hint:  for odd primes the expansion will repeat, though the repeating block will not go all the way to the  units digit.

Comment: So, have you worked out any examples?  It isn't too hard to do this by hand a find a pattern...

Comment: @XanderHenderson $l$ even was easy. $l$ odd: $$ \frac{1}{2} = \sum_{-1}^{\infty} z_i\cdot l^{-i} $$ . We take $z_i$ = $\frac{l-1}{2}$. Am I right. I'm pretty sure this is the right solution. found this pattern through examples. How can I prove it?

Comment: For $p$ odd the sequence of integers $a_n = \frac{1+p^n}{2}$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Its limit is the inverse of $2$. Can you make it into a $p$-adic series ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $l$ is even, $$\frac{1}{2}=0.(\frac{l}{2})00\cdots,$$ because $\frac{l}{2}\cdot l^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Get it. I don't even know why i was so confused. Attempt for l odd: $$ \frac{1}{2} = \sum_{-1}^{\infty} z_i\cdot l^{-i} $$ Take $z_i$ = $\frac{l-1}{2}$.

Comment: @Mugumble: $\sum_{-1}^\infty (\frac{l-1}{2})\cdot l^{-i}$ does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}_l$. On the other hand, $\sum_{-1}^\infty (\frac{l-1}{2}) \cdot l^{i} = -\frac{1}{2l}$. However, you are close. Look at reuns' hint above. Or alternatively, consider this: $\sum_{0}^\infty l^n = \frac{1}{1-l}$. So for any $x$, we have $\sum_{0}^\infty x\cdot l^n = \frac{x}{1-l}$. So which $x$ do you want to choose to make the right hand side $=1/2$?